# Can Beauty be raised or measured in Black/White, other than by Feebas' evolution?

Tags: pokemon-fifth-generation

Prior to *Pokémon Black/White*, Feebas evolved if its Beauty was high enough. According to Bulbapedia, a Feebas with sufficient Beauty traded from an earlier game will still evolve in Black/White.

Other than this, is there any way in *Pokémon Black/White* or *Black/White 2* to change or measure a Pokémon's Beauty stat?

Comment: In Gen 5, you can evolve your Feebas by trading it while it is holding a [Prism Scale](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Prism_Scale#Prism_Scale).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generation V removed contests, and therefore provides no methods to raise or check any of Contest stats of a Pokémon, excluding the Feebas evolution for checking Beauty.

There are a few approaches involving third-party tools to viewing the stats of your Pokémon in detail (such as dumping the save, or tricking the game to use an incorrect GTS server), and since the old contest stats are still present on a Pokémon (which is why the classic Feebas evolution still works), you can use one of those to view these stats. However, they have no effect at all in Generation V (again, excluding Feebas evolution), so there's not much point in doing so.

Answer (score 0):

Generation V removed contests, and thus any method of leveling Contest stats. Since Beauty can no longer be increased, Feebas was given an alternate evolution method. Any Feebas traded with a Prism Scale (obtainable on Route 13, in Undella Town, or through Pickup) will evolve into Milotic.